# wavlete transform vs (scaled) Gabor transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

I've read about the scaled Gabor transform
$$(G_\Psi f)(b,a)(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\Psi(\frac{x-b}{a})e^{-i\omega x}dx$$
and the wavlete transform
$$(L_\Psi f)(b,a) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\Psi(\frac{x-b}{a})dx$$
and obviously they look kind of simular.
So my question is: is there an intuitive way to think about them and their difference?
I know that the scaled Gabor transform is basically a windowed Fourier transform.